# Parsing 256-bit integers in rust extension module

Tags: rust

I am writing a cpython extension module in rust and I want to parse pythons arbitrary precision integers to unsigned 256-bit integer in rust. My source file looks like this:

```
extern crate cpython;

use cpython::{PyResult, Python, py_module_initializer, py_fn};
use num_bigint::BigUint;


py_module_initializer!(mylib, |py, m| {
    m.add(py, "__doc__", "This module is implemented in Rust.")?;
    m.add(py, "add_one", py_fn!(py, add_one(val: BigUint)))?;

    Ok(())
});

fn add_one(_py: Python, val: BigUint) -> PyResult<BigUint> {
    Ok(val + BigUint::from(1u64))
}
```

When I try to compile it with `cargo build --release` I get errors:

```
  --> src/lib.rs:11:26
   |
11 |     m.add(py, "add_one", py_fn!(py, add_one(val: BigUint)))?;
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `FromPyObject<'_>` is not implemented for `BigUint`
```

```
   --> src/lib.rs:11:26
    |
11  |     m.add(py, "add_one", py_fn!(py, add_one(val: BigUint)))?;
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ToPyObject` is not implemented for `BigUint`
```

I understand what this means, but I am unsure how to write a converter from the PyObject to my desired datatype.

---

How do I conveniently parse python integers into unsigned 256-bit integers (BigUint)?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, but it involves using bytes instead of python integer:

```
fn add_one(_py: Python, val: &[u8]) -> PyResult<()> {
    let mut ans = BigUint::from_bytes_le(val);
    println!("bytes before={}", ans);
    ans = ans + BigUint::from_bytes_le(b"\x01");
    println!("bytes after={}", ans);

    Ok(())
}
```

And in python I can write:

```
bytes = int.to_bytes(2**256 - 2, 32, 'little')
mylib.add_one(bytes)
```

Output:

```
bytes before=115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639934
bytes after= 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
```

This bytes can then be converted back to an integer which equals `2**256 - 1` (the max value for unsigned 256-bit integer)